# Angular add dependencies in controller

Tags: angularjs

I want to add module dependencies based on controllers. I don't always need all the dependencies which is killing for the performance of the app. Is there a way to add dependencies into a controller?

```
var angularApp = angular.module('myModule', [
    'angular-cache', 'mwl.calendar', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute'
]);
```

Comment: Make different modules for different work and make them dependent to each other not controllers.

Comment: First of all: why is the question not useful? And isn't there another method instead of creating new modules with all the same config except the dependencies?

Comment: Its Angular structure thats the way it works you can have dependent modules controllers are not dependent on other controllers they depend on modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependencies need to be handled on the module level. So, every module includes what it needs.

What you can do is define separate module for your app and add the controller to that module. Example:

Main module:

```
var angularApp = angular.module('myModule', [
    'angular-cache', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'ScheduleModule'
]);
```

Sub-module:

```
angular.module('ScheduleModule', [
    'mwl.calendar'
]);
```

Controller part of the submodule:

```
angular.module('ScheduleModule').controller('MyContoller', function(){
.............
});
```

This is really the way to go. As your app grows you will start to see the benefits of it, even if you maybe don't see them now. There is a lot of good content on the web about the angular app  modularity and I don't want to copy/paste, so you can do a little research and hopefully it will be more clear.

Comment: But how can i then handle the interpolateProvider for the starting symbol? Do i need to rewrite them everytime again and again?